# Dspace approved item email notification to all user in accept/reject workflow

Tags: dspace

By default, DSpace sends an email notification to the submitter only when an item get approved, but it does not send it to the accept/reject workflow user, I need to send the email notification to all the user's who have the accept/reject permission in the collection

Please help

Thanks

Comment: Seems not to be a SO question

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to modify the code in dspace-api for this.  In DSpace 6, the message is composed and sent in dspace-api/src/main/java/org/dspace/workflowbasic/BasicWorkflowServiceImpl.java, in method 'notifyOfArchive'.  The accept/reject users are the members of an EPersonGroup identified by one of the  properties workflowStep1/workflowStep2/workflowStep3 of the Collection into which the Item is being installed.  I haven't yet found clear documentation of which group does what, but that should narrow your search a bit.

[edit] Apparently both the workflowStep1 and workflowStep2 groups can accept or reject.  workflowStep3 can commit the submission to the archive but cannot reject it.

See https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC6x/Functional+Overview#FunctionalOverview-WorkflowSteps